# Use a password to protect a text file

Tags: windows-7, password-protection

Is there any easy/simple way to protect a .txt file with a password? So whenever open the file, password is required, just like opening .pdf with a password protected. Though I still want to be able to edit the text file in general text editors (notepad).

Comment: Right click -> properties -> Encrypt

Comment: EFS is not fully supported on Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, and Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: A word of warning, @Sathya's solution isn't very portable. It's difficult to get it to work on more than just your user account on one computer, and the encrypted form can't really be transferred to others. It also requires a NTFS file system, which means you can't transfer it onto a flash drive (it's automatically unencrypted when used/transferred).

Comment: That should be a "can't transfer it onto a non-NTFS flash drive, which is the majority of them...

Comment: @Bob: isn't that the first thing you do with a flash-drive, format it into NTFS?

Comment: Stan, what version of Windows 7 have you purchased - Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate?

Comment: I got a Win 7 Ultimate.

Comment: IF you have a lot of data to encrypt then the best option will be to use truecrypt. It provides the best and fastest on the fly encryption.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use NotePad++ and add SecurePad Plugin.
Check this link:
 http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/encrypt-notepad-text-documents-with-securepad-plugin/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/SecurePad/

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Can you provide more context? A name of the software and a small summary? If the link goes dead, we have little helpful information. For example, this solution requires Notepad++. That is an important detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 7-zip, compress and encrypt the file together.
Also for doc files you can use build in office functionality.

[More Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/170352/how-to-password-protect-files-and-folders-with-encryption/)